# Escape XML using stringutils commons.lang version3 apply on writer

Tags: java, filewriter, apache-commons-lang, stringescapeutils, apache-commons-lang3

In the older version of "org.apache.commons.lang"(2.6) StringEscapeUtils, there is a [method to escapexml](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml(java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String)) by passing an instance of "java.io.Writer" as one of the parameter.

eg: `escapeXml(Writer writer, String str)`

But, in newer version 3 StringEscapeUtils, no available method accepts an instance of "java.io.Writer" as one of the parameter.

Is there any alternative to use the writer in an indirect way, setup a callback or handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*All* the overloads accepting a `Writer` have been removed - but instead, `CharSequenceTranslator` instances are available, so you could write:

```
StringEscapeUtils.ESCAPE_XML10.translate(input, writer);
```

(Personally I'd strongly recommend using an XML-focused API to write XML rather than doing it "somewhat manually" like this, admittedly...)

Comment: I'm using OracleWebRowSet and it didn't escape the Special characters like ampersand in text content so resorted to Stringutils in commons lang... so before invoking `OracleWebRowSet.writeXml(FileWriter)`, I need to escape it somehow. to avoid xml parse error